# Selecting a sentence based on specific words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

**Layman's Terms:**

I'd like a sentence that includes the terms: cervical, C[1-5], and/or T[1-6], but does not include lumbar, T[7-9], and/or T1[0-2].

**Example:**

** FINDINGS **: Minimal dextroscoliosis of the spine centered at lumbar C3.

**Desired Output:**

`no sentence selected`

**Attempt #1:**

I tried using the if-then statement. If the sentence doesn't contain these terms then check if the sentence contains the terms I want.

*Regex:*
`[^.]*(?(?!lumbar|T[7-9]|T1[0-2][^.]*?\.)((?i)cervi[cx][^.]*?\.)|((C[1-7]|T[1-6])(?(?=\.)[^.]*?\.|\D[^.]*?\.)))`

*Output:*
** FINDINGS **: Minimal dextroscoliosis of the spine centered at lumbar C3.

**Attempt #2**

I tried following a format I read online, you chain the words you want with the words you don't want in a sentence

*Regex:*
`[^.]*(?=((?i)cervi[cx][^.]*?\.)|((C[1-7]|T[1-6])(?(?=\.)[^.]*?\.|\D[^.]*?\.)))(?!lumbar|T[7-9]|T1[0-2][^.]*?\.)`

*Output:*

** FINDINGS **: Minimal dextroscoliosis of the spine centered at lumbar C3.

**Attempt #3**

I hypothesized that maybe `[^.]*` was not matching with my logic, so I moved it inside the if statement at the negative lookahead group and then group.

*Regex:*

`(?(?![^.]*lumbar|T[7-9]|T1[0-2][^.]*?\.)[^.]*((?i)cervi[cx][^.]*?\.)|((C[1-7]|T[1-6])(?(?=\.)[^.]*?\.|\D[^.]*?\.)))`

*Output:*

** FINDINGS **: Minimal dextroscoliosis of the spine centered at lumbar C3.

So any help is appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: Maybe try to do it in two steps. Find the sentences which contain the desired terms. Discard the sentences which include forbidden words.

Comment: @virolino, that's what I ended up doing. Identified sentences based on the words I wanted then removed the sentences that included the words I didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in two steps. Identified sentences based on the specific words I wanted then out of these removed sentences that included words I didn't want.